# Fatal Error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: graphics, opengl, gpu, raspberrypi

I'm trying to install Urho3D on RPi 3. (GPU = 768 MB)

I installed all the essential dependencies. All the steps went fine. Until this error which occurred during the final make step:

```
[ 56%] Building CXX object Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/Graphics/Skybox.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/Graphics/Graphics.cpp.o
In file included from /root/Urho3D/Source/Urho3D/Graphics/../Graphics/GraphicsImpl.h:29:0,
                 from /root/Urho3D/Source/Urho3D/Graphics/Graphics.cpp:34:
/root/Urho3D/Source/Urho3D/Graphics/../Graphics/OpenGL/OGLGraphicsImpl.h:36:23: fatal error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GLES2/gl2.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/build.make:1916: recipe for target 'Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/Graphics/Graphics.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/Graphics/Graphics.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1198: recipe for target 'Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any suggestions? What should I do !?

Comment: Install `libgles2-mesa-dev` maybe?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver for your comment. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I got similar error when I compiled other project. As @steeldriver suggested, I solved this issue by installing the library:

```
sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa-dev
```